# Unable to take screenshot in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to take a screenshot of the Android emulator when it is started with GPU on but unfortunately the image resulted in blank. It only displays a black screen.
Also *fb0* is not generated after booting the emulator with GPU on.
Any idea or API on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to edit the affected device in the Android Virtual Device Manager, and **uncheck** "Use Host GPU" under Emulation Options near the bottom of the window.

Comment: I need to boot the emulator with GPU on

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the Emulated Performance Graphics: to `Software - GLES 1.1`

1. Open AVD Manager
2. Select the AVD and choose Edit
3. Under Emulated Performance Graphics: select `Software - GLES 1.1`
4. Click Finish
5. Launch your emulator

[image]